# Django: NoReverseMatch when changing to relative url

Tags: django

When I change the line

`<a href="/rango/category/{{category.slug}}">`

to

`<a href="{% url 'show_category' category.slug %}">`

I get NoReverseMatch. What's going wrong?

URLs:

```
app_name="rango"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/',
        views.show_category, name='show_category'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
]
```

[image]

Comment: Some of your patterns are missing a `$` at the end to match the end of the url path. As a result, no url will e.g. ever reach the `add_page` view as it is already matched by the `show_category` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the app name as `rango`. You need to use this when reversing the url:

```
<a href="{% url 'rango:show_category' category.slug %}">
```